# Firebase Auth: Limit phone auth to max one session

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm planning to use Phone Auth for my app, but the requirement is for a single phone number to have only one session. Just like Whatsapp. Is it possible with Firebase Auth? Any suggestions on how to workaround is appreciated as well.

Thanks all

Comment: This is not possible. You can have multiple Firebase Auth sessions. You would not need build that on your own and it will be client side only. You can track each sign in with something like real-time database and force signout on all existing sessions older than the latest.

Answer (score 0):

This has been communicated to Firebase team and an internal ticket has been created to address this.

Comment: Any link or update to this?